How to get probabilities when using score batch in Pyspark with Feature Store?
I'm using from databricks.feature_engineering import FeatureEngineering functions for the future store.
I'd like to perform a score batch inference.
After logging a simple RF classifier:
fe = FeatureEngineeringClient()
fe.log_model(
       model=model,
       artifact_path=artifact_path,
       flavor=flavor,
       training_set=training_set,
       registered_model_name=model_name
)

I want to do score batch inference, but I need the probabilities, not just the predicted label.
The score_batch function only retrieves the predicted label. If changed the name of the prediction columns in the classifier, still, the prediction label expected by score_batch has to be double.
prediction_df = fe.score_batch(
  model_uri=uc_modeling.get_lastest_model_uri(), 
  df=batch_input_df)

Thanks!

you can use this code logged_model = path_to_model loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model) import pandas as pd loaded_model.predict_proba(pd.DataFrame(data)) since score batch doesn't support  it.

Thanks @JayashankarGS. Yes, I'm using mlflow.pyfunc better now. The model is in Spark.

Giving it as an answer so that it will help community to find better solution.
Since, score batch doesn't support the predict_proba you load model using
mlflow.pyfunc.load_model and predict probabilities.
Here, is the code.
import pandas as pd 
logged_model = path_to_model
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
loaded_model.predict_proba(pd.DataFrame(data))

Above code loads the model as generic python function but you can also load it
using model type.
Example:
mlflow.<model-type>.load_model(modelpath)

Refer more about this here.
